# Android: How to implement a textview that is to be constantly updated with messages from a queue?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, queue, handler

Background:

I have a textView on my Android application, and I want to update it with messages that I receive from various sources such as network calls (retrofit2), or messages returned from function calls.

I know that I have to store these messages that come in because I could possibly get like 20 messages all at once. I want to also go through each of these messages one by one every few seconds until queue is empty.

If a new message comes in during an empty queue it would immediately send to the Ui to be updated.

Would a **Handler** in this type of situation be a good fit to solve this problem? What about other things like rxjava or coroutines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be working in Kotlin I'd strongly recommend studying LiveData, it's really useful for keeping your UI consistent with your data.

On that note:

```
class SampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _messages = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>()
    val messages: LiveData<List<Int>>
        get() = _messages
    init {
        _messages.value = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    }
    fun dropList(){
        _messages.postValue(_messages.value?.dropLast(1))
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a viewmodel, I used a List of Ints as my message for simplicity sake.

messages: A [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) class, will be updating my textview when it is updated.

_messages: MutableLiveData is a subclass of LiveData that is primarily used for setting/posting Value, generally not for use outside the viewmodel.

dropList() will remove the last element from the list of messages (i.e. most recent)

Here's my MainActivity

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SampleViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.messages.observe(this, Observer {
   if (it.isNullOrEmpty()){
            tv.text = "No messages"
        } else {
            tv.text = it[it.size - 1].toString()
        }
    })

GlobalScope.launch {
        while (true){
            delay(1000)
            viewModel.dropList()
        }
    }
```

I've set an observer on messages so that when I post a new value to _messages it will update my textview with the new value.

I used GlobalScope to run the viewmodel's dropList function as it is a long running coroutine (infinitely so, in this case) so that every 1 second it will execute.

You seem to not have the concrete details of how you will be getting this list of messages but I hope this has been helpful in showing one method in displaying and decrementing the list once you get it.

Comment: Indeed, thank you so much for your thoughtful answer. I haven't really worked at all with handling a constant input of information that needs to be displayed on the UI. I did a quick google search and some keywords appeared like coroutines, handlers, rxjava, etc but I still havent the idea of which is the best way?

Comment: RXJava and LiveData serve similar functions, LiveData has many features that make it a better choice (imo) for mobile development. Coroutines are also something you should put some time into getting a solid grasp on, I needed to use the GlobalScope in my code because without it if I had run an infinite loop of the .dropList() function it would have run on the UI thread, blocking my textview from ever updating with the actual value.

Comment: Handlers are something that every Android developer uses, it's basically just the action that is taken when a Listener is triggered (for instance, onClick is the Handler for the SetOnClickListener Listener). If you haven't had the opportunity to check out the official docs for Android for Android Components I highly recommend. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture It will make your life 100x easier. Their codelabs are also worthwhile to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout contains textview and add adapter, then attach textview to adapter.
i hope you understand